# returning whole string in Python; Remove None

Tags: python, string, function

I am a beginner in Python and I want to remove all Capital numbers from the string. I have tried below code but getting None after each function call. What should I return from the function?

```
def remove_capitals(a_string):
    for latter in a_string:

        if not (ord(latter) in range(65,91)):
            print(latter,end="")
        else:
            continue

print(remove_capitals("A1B2C3D"))
print(remove_capitals("Georgia Institute of Technology"))
```

I am getting below Output

```
123None
eorgia nstitute of echnologyNone
```

Comment: `else: continue` is pointless at the end of a loop.

Comment: your function is missing the optional `return` statement so it returns the default `None`. if the `print` happens inside the function, remove it from outside and just do `remove_capitals("A1B2C3D")`. Otherwise, instead of printing inside, return it and print it outside.,

Comment: Your function *already `prints()`, then returns `None`*. You then print that return value.

Comment: 123 eorgia nstitute of echnology

Comment: Either return a single result at the end of your function and not print inside the function, or remove the `print()` calls around `remove_capitals()`.

Comment: But what if I want to call the function in print() ? then what should I return?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generator expression with in `str.join` to remove all uppercase letters, which are enumerated in `string.ascii_uppercase`

```
from string import ascii_uppercase
def remove_capitals(a_string):
    return ''.join(i for i in a_string if i not in ascii_uppercase)

>>> print(remove_capitals("A1B2C3D"))
123
>>> print(remove_capitals("Georgia Institute of Technology"))
eorgia nstitute of echnology
```

Comment: **Much** faster: `no_caps = dict.fromkeys(range(65, 91))` then `return a_string.translate(no_caps)`.

Comment: you could pass a list to `join` instead of a generator to speed it up. Otherwise, +1

Comment: `not in ascii_uppercase` means that for any lowercase letter you have to loop over every character in ascii_uppercase.  Couldn't you just use `not char.isupper()`?

Comment: @DSM: that'd expand the possible characters that are removed, when the input uses codepoints outside of ASCII.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: say rather that it wouldn't limit the possible uppercase characters that are removed to the ones the OP hardcoded as "Capital numbers".

Answer (score 1):

Use `isupper`,

```
def remove_upper_case(x):
        return ''.join(i for i in x if not i.isupper())
```

Execution:

```
In [281]: remove_upper_case("Georgia Institute of Technology")
Out[281]: 'eorgia nstitute of echnology'

In [282]: remove_upper_case("A1B2C3D")
Out[282]: '123'
```

Comment: No need for the list expression, a simple generator expression is enough.